# How can I use select with a async_std::io::BufReader?

Tags: rust, async-await, io

I need to read a specific number of bytes from a TUN device set up using https://github.com/yaa110/async-tun.

I also need to control access to a hashmap that can be modified by another future.

```rust
use futures::StreamExt;
const MTU_SIZE: usize = 1500;
let tun: Tun = match TunBuilder::new()
    .name("")
    .tap(false)
    .packet_info(false)
    .up()
    .mtu(MTU_SIZE as i32)
    .try_build()
    .await
{
    Ok(tun) => tun,
    Err(e) => panic!("couldn't create tun device: {e:?}"),
};

use async_std::io::{BufReader, File};
let mut tun_reader: BufReader<&File> = tun.reader();
loop {
    select! {
    p = tun_reader.select_next_some() => { // read from hashmap }
    e = ... => { // possibly add entries to hashmap }
    }
}
```

This does not work because `BufReader<&File>` does not implement `Stream`. Most examples use `.lines().fuse()` to create something that works with `select`, however I don't need lines; I just need a single `[u8; MTU_SIZE]`.

I am clearly in over my head with how rust handles futures, so pointing me to introductory resources in this area is totally OK.

---

After a nap and some advice from @cdhowie below, I think my loop should look something like

```rust
loop {
    let mut packet: Packet = [0u8; 1500];
    let read_task = tun_reader.read_exact(&mut packet).fuse();
    pin_mut!(read_task);
    select!{
    p = read_task => { // read from hashmap }
    e = ... => { // possibly add entries to hashmap }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've imported `async_std::io::prelude::*` then you'll have access to [`ReadExt`](https://docs.rs/async-std/latest/async_std/io/prelude/trait.ReadExt.html), which has methods for obtaining futures from an async `Read` value, such as a `BufReader`.  In this case you likely want `tun_reader.read_exact()`, passing it a mutable slice into a `[u8; MTU_SIZE]`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I think this will work for blocking code, but from my limited understanding, I need to to use `select!` to join whatever future is polling data from the `tun` with the future that will update the hashmap. So I would need to convert the `tun` reader to a `Stream` that outputs `[u8; MTU_SIZE]`. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your explanation, so an example might help.

Comment: @BenLittle `ReadExt::read_exact()` returns a future; it is not blocking.